# Integration Broker Setup

Tags: message-queue, messaging, peoplesoft, service-operations

I am new to using peoplesoft/peoplecode and have a question if anybody could help.  We have a web service that will let you insert values that will be stored into Table A on Database A.  I am trying to use integration broker so that when that Table is being updated on Database A, the same exact table will be updated on Database B.  On the service for Database A, I have made a rowset message containing the table, the que for it, the service and service operation.  The service operation routes the message to the local node on Database B and uses a application class handler to insert data into the table.  For some reason, when I go to the web service to add a row to the table, no message is put into the q.  It seems to not notice that I am trying to send it to the other database(Database B), but it does update Database A.  Any ideas of stuff I can check to fix this error, or do I need to set something up on the service for Database B?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn, creating the message definitions and services are not enough.
You have to write some peoplecode to trigger the WS for you.

If you have done that, please share the code so we can check for the error. If not, do it ;)